# How can I iterate through loop with list variable of another class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working with C#. I have a Employee class and I'm getting employee data from a URL then I created a list named EmpList in another class which is being populated with that information. I'm not getting the location of each employee so I want to hard code the location by making a set location function in Employee class. 
The name 'EmpList' does not exist in the current context.

I've tried to make setLocation function in CreateEmpList function and I got no error but location was empty.
I know I'm probably doing something silly but I really need some help here. I really appreciate that. 
Thankyou.

This is my employee class.

```
public class Employee
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public Guid ID { get; set; } 
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public void SetLocation()
    {

        foreach (var item in EmpList) // I'm getting error here
        {
            if (item.Email == "abc@gmail.com")
            {
                item.Location = "US";
            }
    }
```

And here I'm populating the list in another class.

```
    private List<Employee> EmpList = null;
        private void CreateEmpList(SPHttpClient client)
        {
            List<Employee> SortedList = new List<Employee>();
            JObject jsondata = client.ExecuteJson(UriResources); 
            string strjsondata = jsondata.First.First.First.First.ToString();
            JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(strjsondata);

            foreach (var item in jsonArray) //  Creating master resources list
            {
                ResourcesExcemptList.ForEach(i => i.ToLower()); 

             if(!ResourcesExcemptList.Contains(item["ResourceEmailAddress"].     
             ToString().ToLower()))
             {
                    if (Boolean.Parse(item["ResourceIsActive"].ToString()))
                    {
                        Employee emp = new Employee();
                        emp.ID = (Guid)item["ResourceId"];
                        emp.Email = item["ResourceEmailAddress"].ToString();
                        emp.Name = item["ResourceName"].ToString();
                        emp.Practice = item["ResourceGroup"].ToString();
                        emp.ApproverID = 
                       (Guid)item["ResourceTimesheetManageId"];

                        SortedList.Add(emp);
                    }
                }
            }
            EmpList= SortedList.OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToList();
            //private void setLocation(){  } 
}
```

Comment: You need to make `EmpList` available outside of the class you have defined it in - either using a property or a method, depending on your case. Only then will you be able to access it within the `Employee` class.

Comment: @AnoopRDesai I made a property  `public List<Employee> EmpList{ get; private set; }`  but in location i'm getting null.

Comment: Yes, you need to have called `CreateEmpList()` before you access it in the `Employee` class.

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Answer (score 2):

### The direct answer to your question

The main issue here is that you're not understanding how object oriented code works. You're not using `this`, and you seem to be confused when the class method will be executed and what that means.

Oddly, when in a class method, you still expect that you need to look through the list to find the correct object.  That's the opposite of how you should approach it.

**When an object's class method is being executed, you obviously already have found the object whose method you want to call**. Because otherwise you wouldn't have been able to call that object's class method.

So what you need to do here is to iterate over the list *before* you call the object's class method, not after. Your `Employee` class:

```
public void SetLocation()
{
    this.Location = "US";
}
```

And then:

```
private void CreateEmpList(SPHttpClient client)
{
    // the rest of the code

    EmpList = SortedList.OrderBy(o => o.Name).ToList();

    foreach(var employee in EmpList)
    {
        employee.SetLocation();
    }
}
```

---

### Footnote

Your question shows a basic confusion on OOP principles, but the code itself shows a different level of grasp on OOP principles. I suspect that you didn't write this code yourself, but a colleague did.

I'm mentioning this because I noticed the comment in your example code:

```
//private void setLocation(){  }
```

Notice how its signature is that of a method definition, not that of a method call!

What I think has happened is that your colleague annotated the code and placed a reminder for you to create a method, and you've ended up implementing this method in the `Employee` class instead of in the other class (the one with the `CreateEmpList` method in it).

Creating the method in the other class makes a lot more sense than putting it in the `Employee` class. Something along the lines of:

```
public void SetLocation(Employee employee)
{
    employee.Location = "US";
}
```

Comment: Yup I was working on my colleague's code. I Was confuse in a concept, now I've got it clear. Thank you so much for help :)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, based on my comments:

Declare `EmpList` as:
`public List<Employee> EmpList { get; private set;}`

Then in your `Employee` class:

```
public void SetLocation()
{
    var otherClassObj = new otherClassObj(); // Or perhaps some other way of getting the object of the other class.

    otherClassObj.CreateEmpList(client); // You may have to change this.

    foreach (var item in otherClassObj.EmpList)
    {
        if (item.Email == "abc@gmail.com")
        {
            item.Location = "US";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your main concern is set location value and if empty then set hardcode value then consider this solution:

```
    private string _location;
    public string Location
    {
        get { return _location; }
        set
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                _location = "US";
            }
            else
            {
                _location = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:  public void `SetLocation(List<Employee> EmpList)` allows the code inside `SetLocation()` to access the list object (passed by reference) but I doubt this is what you really want to do.  (No offense;-)

Your logic isn't clear but surely within `CreateEmpList()`,

```
emp.Email = ... 
if (emp.Email...) emp.Location = "..."
```

or within `Employee`, something like

```
public string Email { get {} set { Email = value; if (value...) Location = "..."; } }
```